# Is it possible to combine a reflection (using cubemap) with a material on Three.js?

Tags: reflection, three.js, textures, opacity

If I have an object in three.js which has a texture applied to it (a colourful texture), for example a car - how can I add a partial reflection to the surface, so that the final material is say, the combination of a shiny red metal and the reflection of the scene?

I am familiar with creating reflections using an additional camera and cube mapping, but I am not sure how to combine this with an objects existing material.

An example of the reflection method I am using can be found here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/4d1dd95d62ff48b1842bf4e3fe0c393f5bd6f4d6#commitcomment-1832509

If it is possible to combine the materials, is it possible to control the opacity of each part (the original material vs the reflection) to control how 'reflective' a surface is?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is the `reflectivity`, not the `opacity` that controls how reflective the surface is.

See this example: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap.html

EDIT: This example does not show a texture applied to the material, but in the example above, that can be added like so:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'texture.jpg' );

var cubeMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    ambient: 0xffffff,
    map: texture,
    envMap: reflectionCube
} );
```

(Side note, `cubeMaterial1` in the example is the material applied to the mesh -- in spite of the unusual choice for the variable name.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree with you regarding opacity, I was just trying to use that to describe the reflectivity. I had assumed that to simulate reflectivity you had to use a cubemap combined with some kind of opacity since true reflections aren't possible. The final step you mention is the one I am unsure of - how do I add a texture as well as a reflection material? Thanks

Comment: I expanded the answer for you. There are lots of parameter and material choices. You'll just have to experiment a bit. :-)